Does "occupied space" include terrain?
The 2024 Player's Handbook defines (in the glossary) "occupied space" this way:

A space is occupied if a creature is in it or if it is completely filled by objects.

An "object" is defined as:

An object is a nonliving, distinct thing. Composite things, like buildings, comprise more than one object.

The Warrior of Shadow Monk subclass gains the Cloak of Shadows ability at level 17. Part of the ability when activated is that the monk becomes

Partially Incorporeal. You can move through occupied spaces as if they were Difficult Terrain. If you end your turn in such a space, you are shunted to the last unoccupied space you were in.

Question
Can the monk pass through the solid rock of a cave wall into another chamber, provided that the open space on the other side is within difficult terrain movement distance, or, does "completely filled with objects" not apply to the landscape itself (because the space is occupied not by a "distinct thing"), and the intent is to allow the monk to pass through a space for example that is filled by a pile of logs or a building?
I'd say yes the monk can pass through the cave wall if there is space to reach on the other side within difficult terrain movement distance, but I don't think the intention of the rules is really clear.
I guess this question could be rephrased as, "Is terrain an object?"
There's this answer to What is considered an object? which argues that "an object is any physical thing that is not a creature".
On the other hand the Dungeon Master's Guide (2014) says that

For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, not a building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.

but in that case "for the purpose of these rules", from the context, looks like it is referring to destroying objects.
The 2024 edition of the Dungeon Master's Guide doesn't appear to contain similar text, that I've found.

Someone removed my last comment, but I think it's worth mentioning: you are referring to terrain as a technical term in a manner inconsistent with the game usage. For example, difficult terrain is terrain, but anyone can pass through it. It seems to me that you are actually asking about material, not terrain and you may want to update your question accordingly.

Terrain isn't a space
You looked for the game's relevant definitions, and it appears that they didn't specifically define 'space', so you can fall back to the commonly accepted definition. A 'space' would be an open area that can contain a creature or object, and terrain like solid walls wouldn't count. I could say 'There's a lot of space in this kitchen', but you wouldn't expect me to be including the fridge in that space.
The other way that you could use 'space' is like in board games, which should closely match the game's use. A space is a place that you can put a piece, and game boards that show solid walls usually black them out and/or don't include them in the grid that creates the spaces for pieces. An example would be Stratego, which has ponds in the middle of the board to block movement that don't have grid spaces on them.
So your monk can move through anywhere while partially incorporeal that they could move otherwise, even if those places have other creatures or large objects that would have to be moved, but not a solid wall.
The monk is only partially incorporeal
The name of the ability helps establish the limitation on not moving through solid walls and the like. The monk still has some physical form that can flow around objects and through narrow spaces, but solid terrain like stone walls don't have any room for that last physical bit to squeeze into.

If it's helpful for the answer, the quoted text from the 2014 DMG in the question is now included in the 2024 PHB: "What Is an Object?
For the purpose of the rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone. It isn’t a building or a vehicle, which are composed of many objects."

I would prefer if this answer focused less on colloquial definitions for 'space' and more upon how the game defines it with appropriate definitions from the rules. Right now, this answer seems like it's how you would interpret it, but isn't really RAW.

The assertion that the monk is 'partially incorporeal' and therefore some part of them is solid doesn't really hold up. There's a few ways to interpret that term and none of them are defined by the game. One way is that the character needs to end their turn in an open space and not inside of an object otherwise they're shunted to the 'last unoccupied space'. For reference the Ghost (2014) says, "Incorporeal Movement: The ghost can move through other creatures and objects as if they were difficult terrain. It takes 5 (1d10) force damage if it ends its turn inside an object."

RAW: The Partially Incorporeal Monk Can Pass Through Solid Material
As you've cited, the Incorporeal Monk can:

... move through occupied spaces as if they were Difficult Terrain.

Technically, a space can be occupied by composite Objects because:

Composite things, like buildings, comprise more than one object.

Additionally:

A space is occupied if a creature is in it or if it is completely filled by objects. (emphasis mine)

For example, a cave wall, while not an Object per se, can reasonably be considered a "composite object" that is completely filled by Objects such as the rocks and boulders that compose it.
The 2024 PHB explicitly identifies stones as objects:

For the purpose of the rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a ... stone.

Thus, the Partially Incorporeal Monk should have no trouble passing through it.

It should be "The 2024 PHB explicitly identifies stones as objects: [...]"

@Tarod, Thanks.

I'm unclear on why this answer has so many downvotes, I think it is much better supported than the other answer.

For reference, it may be helpful to also cite other effects in the game relating to moving through walls like Gaseous Form, Etherealness, etc. Especially given the feature in question is acquired at 17th level; this isn't intended to be a throw away 3rd level ribbon.

@Pyrotechnical Feel free to edit the answer to include anything you think is worth mentioning.
